# I am new to Programming. I am stuck in adding the elements of an associative array taking 10 elements each time

Tags: php, associative-array

I have tried the following way; but can it be done in any other way?

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
      "text"=>"1,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,4,2,2,4,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,2,4,3,3,2,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,1,4,1,1,4,2,2,2,2,3"
      );
      
      foreach( $arr as $question=>$answer ) {
        $ext = ((Integer)$answer[0]+(Integer)$answer[2]+(Integer)$answer[4]+(Integer)$answer[6]+(Integer)$answer[8]+(Integer)$answer[10]+(Integer)$answer[12]+(Integer)$answer[14]+(Integer)$answer[16]+(Integer)$answer[18])/10.0;
        $est = ((Integer)$answer[20]+(Integer)$answer[22]+(Integer)$answer[24]+(Integer)$answer[26]+(Integer)$answer[28]+(Integer)$answer[30]+(Integer)$answer[32]+(Integer)$answer[34]+(Integer)$answer[36]+(Integer)$answer[38])/10.0;
        $agr = ((Integer)$answer[40]+(Integer)$answer[42]+(Integer)$answer[44]+(Integer)$answer[46]+(Integer)$answer[48]+(Integer)$answer[50]+(Integer)$answer[52]+(Integer)$answer[54]+(Integer)$answer[56]+(Integer)$answer[58])/10.0;
        $csn = ((Integer)$answer[60]+(Integer)$answer[62]+(Integer)$answer[64]+(Integer)$answer[66]+(Integer)$answer[68]+(Integer)$answer[70]+(Integer)$answer[72]+(Integer)$answer[74]+(Integer)$answer[76]+(Integer)$answer[78])/10.0;
        $opn = ((Integer)$answer[80]+(Integer)$answer[82]+(Integer)$answer[84]+(Integer)$answer[86]+(Integer)$answer[88]+(Integer)$answer[90]+(Integer)$answer[92]+(Integer)$answer[94]+(Integer)$answer[96]+(Integer)$answer[98])/10.0;
        
        echo($ext);
        echo("\n");
        echo($est);
        echo("\n");
        echo($agr);
        echo("\n");
        echo($csn);
        echo("\n");
        echo($opn);
      }
?>
```

I am calculating ext by adding elements of $arr[0:9] and then calculating its average
I am calculating est by adding elements of $arr[10:19] and then calculating its average
I am calculating agr by adding elements of $arr[20:29] and then calculating its average
I am calculating csn by adding elements of $arr[30:39] and then calculating its average
I am calculating opn by adding elements of $arr[40:49] and then calculating its average

The output is coming in the following manner:

```
2.1
4.1
3.3
3.2
2.2
```

Comment: can you please describe what expected output you want?

Comment: Sure this "can be done in any other way". There are million ways. Has that answer to your question been satisfying for you? If not, then maybe you should think about what question you _actually_ want to ask.

Comment: your code is not doing what you describe in your question.

Comment: The output is correct; but the approach is quite long; if the size of the array increases then I have to keep track of the index every time; that is why I want to know if it can be done dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explode to create an actual array out of your comma-separated values first, divide that into chunks of 10 values each, and then calculate the average for those.

```
$data = array_chunk(explode(',', $arr['text']), 10);

foreach($data as $datum) {
    echo array_sum($datum) / count($datum), "<br>\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/OuX9n